# Android error Dx trouble writing output:already prepared

Tags: android, performance, android-listview

I am building an app using Smack . After running app in Eclipse emulator the apk gets installed successfully but  it seems not responding. after clicking on it I am getting the 
alert "unfortunately the app stopped working ". Please help me to solve the same .
Logcat :

```
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067): Process: com.demo.xmppchat, PID: 1067
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.demo.xmppchat/com.demo.xmppchat.CustomizedListView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at com.demo.xmppchat.CustomizedListView.onCreate(CustomizedListView.java:80)
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
01-13 05:55:17.117: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: LogCat..?? Try to clean your project and run it

Comment: i tried to clean so many times. but still the  output is same

Comment: In console m getting  :Chating] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared

Comment: show your code of Oncreate also

Comment: http://pastie.org/8629235

Comment: @meera You get a NullPointerException at line 80:     `map.put("USER", entry.getName().toString());`, your `entry` or `entry.getName()` might be null.

Answer (score 14):

Open properties of your project -> Java build path -> uncheck "Android Private Libraries" and "Android Dependencies".

Comment: You saved my day :) This must be an accepted answer !